# How do I match the first occurrence of a regular expression in a Julia string and store the match in a new string?

Tags: regex, julia

ChatGPT (which has actually been quite helpful assisting me with with Julia) gave me the code below, but it produces this error: invalid using path: "Regex" does not name a module

```
using Base.Regex

string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
regex = r"\w+"

for match in eachmatch(regex, string)
    println(match.match)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just omit the `Base.Regex` (and note that the mentioned platform claims that 'five' has 5 letters. I mean, it's not precise):

```
julia> string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

julia> regex = r"\w+";

julia> for match in eachmatch(regex, string)
           println(match.match)
       end
The
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog
```